# Copying dynamically allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, memory-management

I am writing a DynamicArray class and got stuck with `resize()` function. It works as expected when I remove line `delete[] temp`. But when I don't it seems copying only the last 2 elements. Am I missing something here??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>



template <typename T, int N>
class DynamicArray
{
private:
    T *m_array;
    size_t m_capacity = N * sizeof(T); // Capacity of the array
    size_t m_size; // Number of added elements
public:
    const int GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;

    DynamicArray(std::initializer_list<T> elements) : m_size(elements.size()) {
        m_array = new T[m_capacity / sizeof(T)];
        std::copy(elements.begin(), elements.end(), m_array);
    }

    DynamicArray() : m_size(0) {
        m_array = new T[m_capacity / sizeof(T)];
    }
    
    void resize() {
        T *temp = new T[m_capacity / sizeof(T) * GROWTH_FACTOR];
        std::copy(m_array, m_capacity / sizeof(T) + m_array, temp);
        m_array = temp;
        delete[] temp;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++){
            std::cout << m_array[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    

};

int main() {
    DynamicArray<int, 5> array = { 1, 22, 3, 4 };
    array.print();
    array.resize();
    array.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 22 3 4 
0 0 3 4
```

Comment: Not causing you a problem yet but you need to implement the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: The setting of the initial capacity as a template parameter is a bit strange. Especially as the capacity can change over the lifetime of the array. A capacity is not realy a part of an dynamic arrays type, so I don't think it should be a template parameter. Just make it a constant like `GROWTH_FACTOR` or a constructor parameter if you want the user to be able to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleteing the memory you just allocated. Resize should work by allocating new memory copying elements from the old memory and then deleteing the old.

Something like this

```
void resize() {
    T *temp = new T[m_capacity / sizeof(T) * GROWTH_FACTOR];
    std::copy(m_array, m_capacity / sizeof(T) + m_array, temp);
    delete[] m_array;
    m_array = temp;
}
```

I would also look at how you multiply the capacity by `sizeof(T)` and then everywhere that you use it, you divide the capacity by `sizeof(T)`. If you eliminate both operations you'll get the same result.

Comment: Additionally, you should write a destructor to clean up the array as well:

   DynamicArray::~DynamicArray() 
   { 
       delete[] m_array; 
   }

Comment: Yes, your class also needs a destructor, a copy constructor, an copy assignment operator, and preferably a move constructor and a move assignment operator. But I guess it's just work in progress. Doing all of this is definitely a good learning tool.

Comment: Then should m_capacity and m_size should be ints? I read somewhere that they should be size_t, but that just makes a big mess in code

Comment: In the standard library they are `size_t` but in my view there's nothing wrong with having them as `int` if that's the interface you prefer.